# In Heinlein's Future History, When Does the Soviet Union Fall?

Tags: future-history

In *The Man Who Sold the Moon*, Harriman attracts support from an anti-communist by suggesting that the SU may "paint" a hammer-and-sickle across the face of the Moon, if America doesn't get there first. So clearly it still exists in 1978. But I don't recall hearing of it later than that, not even in "The Green Hills of Earth".

Is there any mention anywhere of what happened to it, and when/how it eventually fell, as I presume it does?

Comment: Great question! It probably fell during the "interregnum" that's mentioned on the chart, but I know of no explicit reference.